# Trying to do a short circuit && as well as assigning error to a String?

Tags: java, string, variable-assignment, short-circuiting

I am incredibly new to Java and this is actually my first project. I've been googling and reading and trial and error-ing things for days and I am still stuck on two things.

I'm sure they're incredibly easy questions and I feel dumb for asking, but I'm getting frustrated!

1) I need to do a conditional statement that is joined by a short circuit && that will result in any input under 0 and over 100 being an error. However I don't see how this is possible since a number can't be less than 100 AND over 100. Am I missing something?

2) I'm not sure what I have to do to be able to assign a String variable the value of 'error'. I feel like this should be super easy but I can't get it...I just know I can't have it be a print statement.

Thank you so much for any input/advice, I really appreciate it!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char letter;

        Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);    
            System.out.print("Please input your score.");
                int score = input.nextInt();

if (score >= 90)
{
  System.out.println("You have earned the letter grade: A");
}// end if for age >=90
else if (score >= 80)
{
  System.out.println("You have earned the letter grade: B");
} // end else if for >=80
else
{
  if (score >= 70)
  {
    System.out.println("You have earned the letter grade: C");
  }// end if for age >=70
  else
  {
    if (score >= 60)
    {
      System.out.println("You have earned the letter grade: D");
    }// end if for >=60
  else
  {
    System.out.println("You have earned the letter grade: F");
  }
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: You should provide code that matches your question.

Comment: Is there a grade for E?

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to use the correct operator `||`.

```
if (score < 0 || score > 100) { ... }
```

2) In Java single quotes `''` are used for chars and double quotes `""` are used for Strings.

```
String s = "error";
```

Comment: Or you can do `if (!(source >= 0 && score <= 100))`

Comment: Negations should be avoided if possible.

Comment: agreed. I usually avoid them by flipping the "then" and "else" statements in my IDE.